# Java multiple class properties

Tags: java, class, polymorphism

Hey all i have a quick question about objects of a class... im working on a hw assignment, i only want a hint in the right direction, not the whole answer.... basically we have five classes and there are 3 im working with.... the main class reads in a text file which im doing fine, the other is a Files.class Homework.class and a Name.class     when i call a new homework i  also create a new name new files

these are the methods that i have for creating a new homework

```
    homework.class
private int id;
private Name name;
private int section;
private Files files;
private int dateSubmitted;

public Homework(int id, Name name, int section, Files files,int dateSubmitted){
    this.id =id;
    this.name = name;
    this.section = section;         // initialize the homework to given params
    this.files = files;
    this.dateSubmitted = dateSubmitted;

}//end public hwk

public Homework(int id, Name name, int section, int dateSubmitted){
    this.id = id;
    this.name =name;        // the second constructor for the homework class
    this.section = section;
    this.dateSubmitted = dateSubmitted;
    this.files = null;
}// end second init homework

public Homework(String first, String last, int section, int dateSubmitted){ 
    this.id = nextAvailableUid();
    this.section = section;
    this.dateSubmitted = dateSubmitted;     
    this.name = new Name(first,last);
    this.files = null;
}
```

what im trying to do is pass in a first and last section and date which is the third HW method.......

my question is in the main class how do i add a file from the main..... or in main do i have to extend the file and name class and construct it from there and pass it in as a new homework?

ie in main

```
Homework []homework = new homework[size];
Files []files = new Files[size]; 
Name[]name = new Name[size];
//add appropriate code to fill in from here....
```

or is there an easier way in main to implement all the classes... other note im not allowed to modify Homework.class, name.class, or files.class

thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure what your question is. Could you make it more clear?

Comment: in main how would i implement the name.class the files.class and the homeworks.class in a shortened way if possible

Comment: what does `implement the name.class the files.class and the homeworks.class` mean?

Comment: the homework class contains name and files,    the files class contains the list of files submitted by the user..... and the im trying to use the homework method

Comment: Assuming the `Main` object has a reference to the `Homework` object, can you create a method in `Homework` that adds a file to its `Files` array? Something like `public void addFile(Files files)...`. I'm basing this question/suggestion off of your second last paragraph, where you're asking "how do I add a file from the main...".

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if I understood your question correctly but you could create setter//getter for your fields.

```
//Exemple for ID
private int id;
public int getId(){
  return id;
}
public void setId(int value){
  id = value;
}
```

And use them this way:

```
Homework h = new Homework();
h.setId(valueToSet);
```

Comment: i have getters for name id section, to string, dayslate, compareto.... What im trying to do in the main class is cut down on all the class declarations

Comment: And can you create a static method taking in parameters the line your're reading, and returning an instance of the object (This is called a factory)?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is import statements. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html.

Import statements allow you to make one class's file aware of the methods/fields from another class's file.

But it is impossible to tell, given that your question "in the main class how do i add a file from the main" doesn't make any sense.